# How to fill the height of the viewport with tailwind css

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm just trying out Tailwind CSS and want to know how to fill the height of the viewport.

Taking this example HTML from the docs

```
<div class="flex items-stretch bg-grey-lighter">
    <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">1</div>
    <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">2</div>
    <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">3</div>
</div>
```

How do I make it stretch to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 102):

There is a tailwind class named `.h-screen` that translates to `height:100vh;` css. This should work as well. For further details please refer to the [Official Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height/)

Comment: You are wrong to obtain `height:100vh;`you must use `h-screen` instead of `h-full`

Comment: @ced correct, that was a mistake on my side! Thanks

Comment: I think it's valid to note that `.h-full` will only work if the parent's element height is defined. Like:
`<div class="h-56 bg-yellow-300">
<div class="h-full bg-white">This will do the work</div>
</div>`

By not defining the height, this will not work:
`<div class="bg-yellow-300">
<div class="h-full bg-white">This will NOT do the work</div>
</div>`

Comment: @AleksandrKopelevich I think 100vh = 100 viewport height. It has nothing to do with parent height.

Comment: @NitinJadhav Sure. I was talking about the case using h-full, instead of h-screen. Was a bit off topic though, I must admit.

Comment: @AleksandrKopelevich got it now, no problem

Answer (score 35):

You can add `min-h-screen` to the parent `<div>`, this would  fill the height of the viewpoint.

And the difference with `h-screen` is that this will stretch over the screen. It would be helpful when the screen is tiny and the content is overflowing with a scrollbar. In this situation the background will not fill the rest of the scrolled-up part.

```html
 <div class="flex items-stretch bg-grey-lighter min-h-screen">
    <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">1</div>
    <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">2</div>
    <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">3</div>
</div>
```

Link to some snippets at tailwind play (added a background color example to clarify it): https://play.tailwindcss.com/8Qd822yY4w

Answer (score 20):

You can use `.h-screen` class of [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height).

Comment: Surely you meant `h-screen`?

Answer (score 15):

I'm using NextJS + tailwindcss.
NextJS adds a `<div id="__next">`, so this is what I have in my `global.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
html {
  @apply h-full;
}
body {
  @apply h-full;
}
div#__next {
  @apply h-full;
}
main {
  @apply h-full;
}
```

And in my page I have

```
<main className="bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500">
  ...
</main>
```

Comment: Perfect! Came here for the same. :D

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old post, but I found it now, while I was trying to have the background color streched to the size of the screen when the content was too little to fill it and avoid to have the background color to stop suddenly when the content was more of the size of the screen (that happens with h-screen).
I solved the problem using min-h-screen.

Comment: .min-h-screen exactly looking this, like when the console opened  the h-screen not worked well

Answer (score 4):

You may use h-screen class in your main div. Check out more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height)

Answer (score 2):

For mobile, anything related to "h-screen" is going to cause problems because it sets the style to

> height: 100vh

On mobile, the entire screen is seen as 100vh, meaning that your content would overflow the screen. This is due to the dynamic toolbars which are unique to every device. I would recommend you manually setting the height to 100svh to ensure that your content is always rendered correctly regardless of whether you view it on mobile or desktop. To my knowledge, Tailwindcss does not have an option for dynamic view port (yet).

```
<div style="height: 100svh" class="flex items-stretch bg-grey-lighter">
   <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">1</div>
   <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">2</div>
   <div class="flex-1 text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light px-4 py-2 m-2">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the content of the body is too little to fill the whole screen, I would use flexbox to vertically stretch the smaller divs evenly.

Make sure body and the parent div have 100% height, and use flex box as columns and add flex-basis to spread vertically and evenly.

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-1 {
/* or flex-grow: 1; */
flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I figured I might not be the only person here trying to make a full-screen div with a translucent background color... here's an explicit way to do so:

```html
<div className='bg-black bg-opacity-80 h-screen w-screen top-0 left-0 fixed'></div>
```

You can also optionally add `z-10` if a `z-index` is relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for filling the height of the viewport with Tailwind CSS is to use the `h-screen` class.

If you have a specific section you want to adjust within the viewport, you can further customize it using the `h-[calc(100vh_-_150px)]` class, adjusting the height accordingly.